# Can't open files in subdirectories in Perl

Tags: perl, file, subdirectory

I'm having a really hard time.  I'm new to Perl and I'm completely stuck trying to traverse all subdirectories, performing an operation.  It works fine in the root dir (of where my script is), but as soon as it gets to a subdirectory, it bombs.  I've tried surrounding the filename in " or ' or q{} to no avail.  I've searched for this problem on StackOverflow and people are saying it should just work, that open handles subdirs and will accept forward slashes.
It's failing on the first open (reading a file) as soon as it dives into a directory and tries to open './Horse/Models.meta'.  This is after it processed 20 files at the same level as my script.  Any ideas?

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

find(sub {
if (-f and /\.meta$/) {
    print "--> " . $File::Find::name . "\n";
    open my $in,  '<',  $File::Find::name    or die "Can't read old file: $!";
    open my $out, '>', "$File::Find::name.new" or die "Can't write new file: $!";

    while( <$in> )
    {
            if(index($_,"  assetBundleName:")!=-1) {
                    print $out "  assetBundleName: mobs\n";
            } else {
                    print $out $_;
            }
    }
    close $out;
    print("mv -f \"" . $File::Find::name . ".new\" \"" . $File::Find::name . "\"\n");

    system("mv -f \"" . $File::Find::name . ".new\" \"" . $File::Find::name . "\"");

  }
}, '.');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bombs"?

Comment: Please don't use *"bombs"*, *"failing"*, *"doesn't work"* etc. It gives no useful information at all about what the problem may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
rename "$File::Find::name.new", $File::Find::name or die $!;
```

See [rename](http://p3rl.org/rename).

If you want to use the relative path (i.e. $File::Find::name) instead of just the filename (i.e. $_), you need to specify

```
find({ wanted   => sub { ... },
       no_chdir => 1,
}, '.');
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll change that.  But, this still doesn't explain why 
open my $in,  '<',  $File::Find::name    or die "Can't read old file: $!";
is failing on the file ./Horse/Models.meta.  Do you know what could cause that?  It works fine on paths without slashes (root files)

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"? What error do you get?

Comment: Can't read old file: No such file or directory at setAssetBund.pl line 11.

Comment: Okay, added it and ran again:
Can't read old file: (./Animals Horses/Models.meta) No such file or directory at setAssetBund.pl line 11.
(note: some changing of the directory structure has altered the first file encountered in a subdirectory but same issue nevertheless)  This one has a space in the name too.

Comment: Thank you!! This worked!  I didn't no about no_chdir

Answer (score 1):

`$File::Find::name` is the complete pathname to the file relative to the original CWD, but `File::Find` keeps changing the CWD unless you tell it otherwise. Either tell File::Find not to change the CWD using `no_chdir => 1`, or use `$_` instead of `$File::Find::name`. I recommend the former.

---

On an unrelated note, you should use the following to rename files instead of shelling out.

```
rename($old_name, $new_name)
   or die("Can't rename \"$old_name\" \"$new_name\": $!\n");
```

If you need to rename files across file system boundaries, you could use File::Copy's `move`, though shelling out is not so bad then, if done properly:

```
system("mv", "-f", "--", $old_name, $new_name);
die("Error executing mv: $!\n") if $? == -1;
die("mv killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("mv returned error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $? >> 8;
```

Comment: Thank you!! no_chdir was what I was missing.  I didn't realized it was changing cwd's on me!

Comment: This is unrelated but is there a reason you write 0x7F instead of the decimal version? I don't see this used in `perlvar` for `$?` and I'm curious if it matters.